# passing in list from c# to asp.net and it's not getting the data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

**I made the changes Mikey suggested to not use Session but I'm still not getting anything on my map**

I am passing to my asp page a list of lat longs for google maps like this:

```
  public List<string> GetLatLonList()
  {
        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("43.169582 , -76.823404");
        list.Add("43.169133 , -76.822956");
        list.Add("43.169115 , -76.821818");
        list.Add("43.169151 , -76.820488");
        list.Add("43.170049 , -76.820424");
        return string.Join(";", list.ToArray());
      }
```

This is my asp.net page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MultipleMarker.aspx.cs" Inherits="MultipleMarker" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>



<script type ="text/javascript">
  var map; var infowindow;
  var latlons = 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]';

    function InitializeMap() {

      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latlons[0]);
      console.log("latlng:" + latlng);
        var myOptions =
        {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    }

    function markicons() {

        InitializeMap();

        var ltlng = [];

      //        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(17.22, 78.28));
      //        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(13.5, 79.2));
      //        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(15.24, 77.16));

        var length = latlons.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          console.log(latlons[i]);
          ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(latlons[i]));
        }

        map.setCenter(ltlng[0]);
        for (var i = 0; i <= ltlng.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: ltlng[i]
            });

            (function (i, marker) {

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

                    if (!infowindow) {
                        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    }

                    infowindow.setContent("Message" + i);

                    infowindow.open(map, marker);

                });

            })(i, marker);

        }

    }

    window.onload = markicons; 

</script>
<h2>Multiple Markers Demo:</h2>
<div id ="map"   
        style="width: 80%; top: 51px; left: 32px; position: absolute; height: 80%">

</div>
</asp:Content>
```

I'm getting no content on the screen. It is coming up with a blank map. I am getting no javascript errors so I'm not sure why it's not working.

This is my first attempt at javascript. Anyone see why I'm having issues?

EDIT #2 In Response to Mikey

This is the source of the page when run:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="MultipleMarker.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTEwMDUyNjYzMjhkZOATrmZzTn3jrg2qYoyIsT7K8EJcig29Z1QzbaXOQK0d" />
</div>

    <div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>



<script type ="text/javascript">
  var map; var infowindow;
  var latlons = 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]';

    function InitializeMap() {

      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latlons[0]);
      console.log("latlng:" + latlng);
        var myOptions =
        {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    }

    function markicons() {

        InitializeMap();

        var ltlng = [];

      //        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(17.22, 78.28));
      //        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(13.5, 79.2));
      //        ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(15.24, 77.16));

        var length = latlons.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          console.log(latlons[i]);
          ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(latlons[i]));
        }

        map.setCenter(ltlng[0]);
        for (var i = 0; i <= ltlng.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: ltlng[i]
            });

            (function (i, marker) {

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

                    if (!infowindow) {
                        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    }

                    infowindow.setContent("Message" + i);

                    infowindow.open(map, marker);

                });

            })(i, marker);

        }

    }

    window.onload = markicons; 

</script>
<h2>Multiple Markers Demo:</h2>
<div id ="map"   
        style="width: 80%; top: 51px; left: 32px; position: absolute; height: 80%">

</div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you load your page you can "View Source" to take a look at what you're actually outputting.  Also, you do not need (and shouldn't use) a Session variable to do this.  You can add a "protected string getLatLonList" method to your code behind that returns the string you want to use to represent your list. You can insert it into your javascript by doing a <%= getLatLonList() %> instead of <%= Session["LatLonList"] %>.

Comment: Thanks for the info, wasn't aware you could do that. I have made the changes but I'm still not getting anything on the map.

Comment: @ErocM What does viewing the source output? It's likely that the C# method is not returning the list in a format javascript can interpret by itself...

Comment: Yes, if your method returns a string representation of your list, rather than the list itself, you'll be much closer to a solution.  http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-list-string

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have posted the source. What am I looking for?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're CTRL-V-ing things into your pages without understanding them...  The below method(s) will bring you a bit closer..

In your code behind:

```
public string getLatLonList()
{
        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("[43.169582 , -76.823404]"); // this is the center
        list.Add("[43.169133 , -76.822956]"); // these are the marks
        list.Add("[43.169115 , -76.821818]");
        list.Add("[43.169151 , -76.820488]");
        list.Add("[43.170049 , -76.820424]");
        return string.Join(",", list.ToArray());    
        // TODO:  cache the above list so you're not always creating it..  
        // e.g. create the list on Page_Load and simply return its string representation in this method..
}
```

Then in your aspx:

```
var latlons = [<%= getLatLonList() %>];
function InitializeMap() {

  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latlons[0][0], latlons[0][1]);
  console.log("latlng:" + latlng);
```

You'll need to *debug* it..

Here's the other javascript function:

```
function markicons() {
    InitializeMap();

    // TODO: ensure there at least 2 items in the latlons list...
    for (var i = 1; i < latlons.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlons[i][0], latlons[i][1]
        });

        (function (i, marker) {

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

                if (!infowindow) {
                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                }

                infowindow.setContent("Message" + i);

                infowindow.open(map, marker);

            });

        })(i, marker);

    }

}
```

Comment: Something isn't right about the latlons variable. When I do 'console.log("latlng:" + latlng);' it is returning "latlng:(NaN, NaN)".  I have updated my post with the changes.

Comment: Don't actually put "var latlons = 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]';" into your aspx page!  That was simply to highlight what was being output to the users' pages (that was the initial problem).  I updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following link.In this post I am passing complex data to chart API.you can get idea from this post.

[How to used google chart in asp.net[google chart]](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-used-google-chart-in-aspnet.html)

Comment: I added `<asp:HiddenField ID="hdData" runat="server" />` to my form and it still says hdData is not defined.

Comment: my page load is identical to yours, where is hdData defined?

Comment: in the form section <asp:HiddenField ID="hdData" runat="server" />